# Get the parent/ancestor UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML markup that looks like

```
<ul>
  ...

    <li>
      <ul class="x">
        ...
        <a href="#"...
```

How can I get the parent `ul.x` element from a click event hooked on the link?

`this.parentNode` works if the UL is the parent element, but if it's one of the ancestors I have to use `this.parentNode.parentNode` depending on how many parent elements are in between...

Can I somehow get the first UL parent?

Comment: I recommend taking an hour to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com), as you're using jQuery. It will save you a lot of time in the long run. Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance,

You can also use [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like below, jquery [eventObject](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) also has a property named [delegateTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/), which could be useful in your case.

```
$('ul.x').on('click', 'a', function(e){


    //e.delegateTarget is the parent ul of the clicked a tag
    //e.target.id is the clicked a tag

    alert(e.delegateTarget.id); 
    alert(e.target.id);

});​
```

**HTML:**

```
 <ul id='a' class="x">
      <li><a id='1' href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a id='2' href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a id='3' href="#">C</a></li>
 </ul>

 <ul id='b' class="x">
      <li><a id='11' href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a id='21' href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a id='31' href="#">3</a></li>
 </ul>​
```

In terms of performance, you are not binding the event on all the `a` tags. jQuery suggests this way.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sVNG/).

Answer (score 5):

Since you've tagged the question as jQuery:

```
$(this).closest("ul"); //Get the first ancestor `ul`
$(this).closest("ul.x"); //Get the first ancestor `ul` with class `x`
```

Or, without jQuery (since your example doesn't seem to be using jQuery):

```
var node = this;
while(node.tagName !== "UL") {
    node = node.parentNode;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). this will get the closest ancestor that matches the selector you provide it.

```
$(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){         //handler of your <a>
        var ulx = $(this).closest('ul.x'); //find the closest ancestor <ul> with class "x"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if `ul.x` is direct parent of `a` use this:

```
    $('a').on('click',function(){
        var ul = $(this).parent('ul.x');
    });
```

or

```
    $('a').on('click',function(){
       var ul = $(this).closest('ul.x');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) like:

```
$('a').click(function(){    
   var ul = $(this).closest('ul.x'); //or just closest('ul') in case you only used the x for demo purposes
});
```

This will go up the DOM tree and stop at the first match (your `ul.x`-element).